# Azure websites doesn't load the ROOT.war for the default web page

Tags: tomcat, azure

I have a java app that I am pushing to azure per instructions here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-add-app/

The app needs to be in the root directory, so previously on new unix servers I'd name it ROOT.war and restart tomcat for good measure.  I've tried following the instructions of putting the ROOT.war in the /site/wwwroot/webapps directory, I've tried putting it into the /site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT directory, I've tried removing the ROOT directory and restarting the server... no matter what I try the end result is the same - I always see the stock Tomcat7 page.  Is there something I can trigger to get Tomcat to pick up my war file for the root?

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323613/azure-git-continuous-deployment-for-a-java-webapp

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have selected tomcat from the azure websites app gallery and therefore you have the full version of tomcat under /site/wwwroot/ -- please place your ROOT.war under /site/wwwroot/bin/tomcat/webapps.